# Evaluating $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=j+1}^{n-1}1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

> How can I evaluate this triple sum?
> $$\large\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=j+1}^{n-1}1$$

I started to calculate but I struggled in the second internal sum.

**Update**

This is the innermost sum that I tried:
$$\large\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}(n-j-1)$$
$$\large\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}(n-j-1)=\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}n - \sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}j-\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}1$$
$$\large\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}n= n^2 - n - ni$$

Comment: Thanks @Blue by editing.

Comment: Can you evaluate the innermost sum?

Comment: There's one step left until the answer comes out.

Comment: See "tetrahedral number" https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/7731/229

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to evaluate the sums iteratively, working from the inner most to the outer most sum. As we go along, we will need to use the following three identities
$$
\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{m}1 = m}_{\textbf{(A)}},\quad \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{m}i^2 = \frac{1}{2}m(m+1)}_{\textbf{(B)}}, \quad \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{m}i^2 = \frac{1}{6}m(m+1)(2m+1)}_{\textbf{(C)}}, 
$$
for some arbitrary positive integer $m$.

Having laid out the key expressions, we can begin this in the following way.

**Inner Most Sum**

Firstly, note that we can rewrite the inner most sum in such a way that we can apply **(A)**, and indeed doing so, we obtain
$$
\sum_{k=j+1}^{n-1}1 = \sum_{k = 1}^{n-1-j}1 = n-1-j
$$

**Middle Sum**

Having evaluated the inner most sum, we can proceed and obtain the following
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=j+1}^{n-1}1 &= \sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}(n-1-j)\\
\text{separate the sum gives }&= \sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}(n-1) - \sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}j\\
\text{use (A) and (B)}&= (n-1)(n-1-i) - \frac{1}{2}(n-1-i)(n+i)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}(n-1-i)(n - 2 - i) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[(n-1)(n-2) - i(n-1) - i(n-2) + i^2\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[(n-1)(n-2) - i(2n - 3) + i^2\right].
\end{align}
$$
**Outermost Sum**

We are now left with the final sum.
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=j+1}^{n-1}1 
&= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left[(n-1)(n-2) - i(2n - 3) + i^2\right] \\
\text{separate the sum}
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[n(n-1)(n-2) - (2n-3)\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i^2\right] \\
\text{use (A), (B) and (C)}
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[n(n-1)(n-2) - \frac{1}{2}n(n-1)(2n-3) + \frac{1}{6}n(n-1)(2n-1)\right]
\end{align}
$$
Simplifying down, we find that
\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{2}\left[n(n-1)(n-2) - \frac{1}{2}n(n-1)(2n-3) + \frac{1}{6}n(n-1)(2n-1)\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{2}n(n-1)\left[n-2 - \frac{1}{2}(2n-3) + \frac{1}{6}(2n-1)\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{6}n(n-1)(n-2). 
\end{align}
**Final Result**

Thus, we can conclude that
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=j+1}^{n-1}1 = \frac{1}{6}n(n-1)(n-2).
$$

---

**Extension Result**

The above exercise leads to the following interesting exercise. Given some index $m$, what is the evaluation of the sum (whenever it makes sense)
$$
\sum_{i_1=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i_2=i_1+1}^{n-1}\sum_{i_3=i_2+1}^{n-1}\cdots\sum_{i_m=i_{m-1}+1}^{n-1}1 ?
$$

This is quite an interesting question, and yields a very nice answer. Indeed, we have that
$$
\sum_{i_1=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i_2=i_1+1}^{n-1}\sum_{i_3=i_2+1}^{n-1}\cdots\sum_{i_m=i_{m-1}+1}^{n-1}1 = \frac{1}{m!}\prod_{i=0}^{m-1}(n-i) = \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!} = {n \choose m}
$$

You can find out more about sums of this form in this [article](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL13/Butler/butler7.pdf).

Comment: I really appreciate you sharing the solution with us. I would like to ask, if possible of course, if you could mention the sum properties you used?

Comment: @JorgeLuizFigueira I have added a little more detail. Hope this helps. The main trick is to reindex your sums and then apply rules (A), (B) and (C) as needed.

Comment: @JorgeLuizFigueira Just fixed a typo, it should all be correct now

Comment: Wow. I'm feeling smarter in my morning after this. Thank you @Spaceman very much for the detailed explanation!!! This community is amazing.

Comment: @JorgeLuizFigueira Not a problem, glad it helped

Answer (score 1):

The sum is equal to the number of ordered triples of integers $(i, j, k)$ such that $0 \leqslant i < j < k \leqslant n - 1.$ Therefore, it is equal to the number of $3$-element subsets of the $n$-element set $\{0, 1, \ldots, n - 1\},$ which is $\binom{n}3.$ Similarly for the more general result given in Spaceman's answer.